# jQuery: How to find prev or next element based on name?

Tags: jquery, element, selector

Here's what I'm trying to do, simplified:

```
<input rel="TimeStart">
// bunch of HTML code in between
<input rel="TimeEnd">
```

In the Javascript:

```
$("[rel="TimeEnd]").blur(function() {
    // find first previous element named "TimeStart"
    // compare their dates
});
```

I tried using `$(this).prev("[rel=TimeStart]")` but it keeps returning null. Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I ended up abandoning this code. It got way too messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).prevAll("[rel=TimeStart]:first")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).siblings('input[rel=TimeStart]');
```